# Вычисление порождающей точки в группе точек эллиптической кривой

Tags: математика, криптография

Имеется группа точек эллиптическая кривой над конечным полем. Кривая по всем параметрам полностью аналогичная кривой используемой Bitcoin и другими подобными системами (`y² = x³ + ах + b, а = 0 и b = 7`, с тем же порядком и т.п.), за исключением порождающей точки `G`.

Мы знаем что `Q = k*G`, знаем `Q` и `k`, но базовая точка `G` не известна. Как её вычислить?

Comment: По идее нужно инвертировать `k`, вычислить обратное к нему число по модулю вашему. И тогда домножить Q на это обратное число, получим базовую точку.

Comment: По идее да, но почему то при проверке (берем тестовую точку в качестве базовой, умножаем на 5, а потом на 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F - 5), получаю совсем другую точку...

Comment: Попробуйте вот что. Допустим мы обратили k и домножив на Q получили некую базовую G0. Дальше проверьте если k * G0 то получим ли мы исходную Q? Может гипотеза об обращении k не верная для элл кривых? Если мы домножив k * G0 получили исходную Q, но при этом у вас исходная базовая G оказалась другой, то это означает что исходная базовая будет определяться не однозначно, обе базовые вполне будут подходить для этого равенства. Значит точную исходную базовую уже не определить. Кстати вполне возможно что это две одинаковые базовые с точностью до чего то, до модуля или ещё чего то.

Comment: Нет, получаем 3 точку ))) Причем это не сработало даже для базовой точки вышеупомянутого Bitcoin ))

Comment: [55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240, 3267...] * 5 = [21505829891763648114329055987619236494102133314575206970830385799158076338148, 9800...] * (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F - 5) = [21948635701860971088224887311506659163291435857103981071633130180075972556968, 6186...]

Comment: Если все ваши данные (Q, k) не секретные то вы бы могли вставить их в ваш вопрос текстом. Это поможет мне и другим попробовать решить задачу на конкретных примерах. Если именно те что надо точки секретные, но у вас есть пример не секретных (Q, k, G) то укажите их. Кстати если будете указывать, то обязательно укажите верный ответ, верную G, если она у вас есть для этих данных.

Comment: Выше я уже взял для примера базовую точку bitcoin, как общедоступный и явный пример, результат вы видите. Не пойму что я делаю не так... Ведь это же должно работать ))

Comment: Приведите тогда все примеры из Биткоина в вашем посте с вопросом, вставьте текст, чтобы мне и другим не изучать биткоин и не искать его публичные точки или пример личного/публичного ключа. Мне бы помогло чтобы вы готовые точки и данные полные вставили в текст вопроса, я бы уже начал вычислять и пробовать. То что вы прислали в комментариях во первых не оформленные данные, не расписано где Q k G, во вторых урезанные. там многоточие стоит `...` и числа урезанные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы инвертировали 5, но в начальную точку не вернулись, значит ошибка в том, как вы инвертировали.

Ваша тестовая точка порождает циклическую группу порядка N. Инвертировать 5 нужно именно по модулю N: `inv_5 = (5**(N-2))%N`

Тогда `inv_5 * 5 = 5**(N-1)` что по малой теореме Ферма сравнимо с единицей по модулю N (разумеется, если N - простое). Уж точно не нужно вычитать 5 из характеристики поля, над которым определена кривая.

Для проверки я взял кривую `secp256k1`, нашел в интернете точку с известным порядком :) и проверил, как работает инвертирование пятёрки.

```
from ecpy.curves import Curve,Point

cv = Curve.get_curve('secp256k1')
P  = Point(0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798,
       0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8,
           cv)
# порядок точки P: (k*P).is_infinity == True
k  = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141
Q = 5*P
# Инвертируем 5 относительно порядка группы
inv_5 = pow(5, k-2,k) 
# inv_5 == 0x66666666666666666666666666666665e445f1f5dfb6a67e4cba8c385348e6e7
R  = inv_5*Q

R == P # True
```

Если вы инвертируете так же как в примере, возводя в степень N-2, но получается не та точка, значит у вас неверный порядок точки.

[Код для ответа в Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1268254/ec_invert.ipynb)

Comment: Вы правы, я не верно проводил инверсию. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @zemexx.ru.snd так как в secp256k1 у всех точек один и тот же порядок, то инвертирование относительно 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141 должно работать. Если оно не работает, то либо вы обнаружили в математике фундаментальную ошибку и можете претендовать на премию Абеля, либо у вас ошибка в алгоритме :)

Comment: нет премия мне явно не светит, да и не было это целью )) Вам еще раз огромное спасибо!